# Attempt to dereference null object error because emailTextBody is in fact null

Tags: apex, apex-email-service, null-pointer

I have an email service with Apex that drives a class reservations system that reads in a keyword from and email body and will update a record if the sender is coming or not.

I will get an "Attempt to dereference a null object" error from Salesforce when the sender's device does not send both text and html versions of their message. In my field testing this typically happens on cell phones (specifically Android phones using an IMAP account with the GMail app). It seems this occurs enough to warrant a programmatic workaround.

Is there a best practice to handle this case (i.e. set emailTextBody to cleansed emailHtmlBody) or a way to easily convert html-formatted email to text when emailTextBody is null?

Here's a bit from the DEBUG log that ID'd the issue for me ("Nah" was the response I sent):

```
> 16:07:27.0
> (3829841)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[EXTERNAL]|this.plainTextBody|null|0x14fe4157
> 16:07:27.0 (3860820)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[50]|Bytes:5 16:07:27.0
> (3881040)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[56]|Bytes:5 16:07:27.0
> (3888870)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[64]|Bytes:7 16:07:27.0
> (3900243)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:5 16:07:27.0
> (3903302)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:68 16:07:27.0
> (3908651)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[EXTERNAL]|this.plainTextBodyIsTruncated|false|0x14fe4157
> 16:07:27.0 (3923334)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:1664 16:07:27.0
> (3926408)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:68 16:07:27.0
> (3934015)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[EXTERNAL]|this.htmlBody|"\u003Cdiv
> dir='auto'\u003ENah\u003C (1644 more) ..."|0x14fe4157
```

Here is the Apex class (note issue starts on line 14 where I define the KeyWord to look for in emailTextbody and only that function):

```
global class myProcessInboundEmail implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {

    global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.inboundEmail email,Messaging.InboundEnvelope env){

        // Create an InboundEmailResult object for returning the result of the 
        // Apex Email Service
        Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();

        // Try to look up any Enrollments based on the email from address AND Enrollment ID from subject field
        // If there nothing is found an exception will be thrown and the catch statement will be called.
        // The search string used in the subject line.
        string[] EnrollID = email.subject.split('rsvp id: ');
        string enroll_id = EnrollID[1].substring(0,EnrollID[1].length()-1);
        string[] KeyWord = email.plainTextBody.toLowerCase().split('\n');
        string command = KeyWord[0].trim();
        boolean optout = false;

        System.Debug(KeyWord);

        try {
            List<Enrollment__c> enroll=[select Participant__c, RSVP__c, RSVP_Date__c, Last_Message_Received__c, Participant__r.SMS_Opt_in__c from Enrollment__c where Participant__r.JobDeveloper__Email__c=:email.fromAddress and Id=:enroll_id limit 1];

            //Now just need to parse incoming email for real Email_for_Text_Messages__c and Id (enrollment ID in Subject line - maybe in parens)
            if (!enroll.isEmpty()) {
                if (command == 'cancel') {
                    command = 'Canceled';
                } else if (command == 'confirm') {
                    command = 'Confirmed';
                } else if (command == 'yes') {
                    command = 'Confirmed';
                } else if (command == 'no') {
                    command = 'Canceled';
                } else if (command == 'stop') {
                    optout = true;
                } else {
                    command = 'Unconfirmed';
                }    

                //Do the updates
                Enrollment__c enrollment=enroll[0];
                if (optout == false) {
                    enrollment.RSVP__c=command;
                }
                enrollment.Rsvp_Date__c=Datetime.now();
                enrollment.Last_Message_Received__c=Keyword[0];
                update enrollment;

            }
        }

        // If an exception occurs when the query accesses 
        // the contact record, a QueryException is called.
        // The exception is written to the Apex debug log.
        catch (QueryException e) {
            System.debug('Query Issue: ' + e);
        }

       // Set the result to true. No need to send an email back to the user 
       // with an error message
       result.success = true;

           // Return the result for the Apex Email Service
       return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`String`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) class has a `stripHtmlTags` method.

```
String body = email.plainTextBody;
if (body == null) body = email.htmlBody.stripHtmlTags();
```

If you are trying to split out the first line, you may need to also consider how that will be represented in html and update your parsing logic accordingly. You might need to replace certain tag(s) with line break characters (`\n`) before you strip out all html.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Now I'm having issues with compiling after adding this to my code.

`Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void htmlBody() from the type Messaging.InboundEmail`

Am I calling it wrong?

Comment: Remove the parens after. My mistake.